# "Change Comparison Branch" option missing in TFS 2017

Tags: git, tfs

Just upgraded to TFS 2017.  In TFS 2015 as well as Visual Studio Team Services you can change the comparison branch, however my UI in 2017 does not have this option in the drop down.

This is what my drop down option looks like in 2017

[image: On Premise TFS 2017 missing option]

Here is what the option looks like on Visual Studio Team Services.

[image: Visual Studio Team Services with option]

I'm not sure if this is a feature that is currently only in the Visual Studio Team Services version or if somehow this option is turned off/broken in my on prem version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was added to Visual Studio Team Services after the freeze for RTM of TFS 2017 (on 16 oct 2016), so I suspect it'll show up in TFS 2017 update 1:

> ### Configurable compare branch

> You can now set your compare branch to something other than the default branch. This setting will be remembered on a per-user basis. Pull requests and new branches created from the Branches page will be based off the branch you set as the compare branch.

> Your default branch will automatically be set as the compare branch as denoted by the badge.

> **default compare**

> You can change the compare branch by selecting Set as compare branch in the context menu.

> <sub>https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/news/2016/oct-12-team-services</sub>

[The docs don't reflect this correctly at the moment though](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-your-branches?view=azure-devops#change-the-compare-branch).

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted a UserVoice at website below, you can vote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17666401-add-configurable-compare-branch-feature-to-tfs20